# Make Bard generate French sentences where all words are pronounced as they are spelt

Tags: bard, french

## Context

In French,

- `le bol` is pronounced how it is spelt (`l`-`e`-`b`-`o`-`l`),
- but `les cieux` is not (`s` and `x` not pronounced, `c` pronounced `s`, `eu` pronounced `e`).

## Goal

I want to make a GenAI tool generate sentences similar to the first bullet, with zero difficulties.

## Problem

Bard generates 90% of outputs that do **not** conform to these rules (same for ChatGPT 3.5 by the way).

What am I doing wrong? My prompt:

```
Tu es un auteur de livres pour enfants.
Donne-moi 10 phrases, en français, composées de mots faciles à lire.
Tous les mots doivent être prononcés exactement comme ils s'écrivent. Par example:
 - "le bol" est OK.
 - "chat" ou "lit" ne sont pas OK car le "t" ne se prononce pas.
 - "ciel" n'est pas OK car le "c" se prononce "s" et non pas comme un "c" dur.
 - "eau" et "des" ne sont pas OK car la prononciation du mot ne correspond pas à la prononciation de chaque lettre.
```

*(Sorry for the French-centric question, I can translate my prompt attempt to English if necessary)*

Comment: @Wicket: Done, thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 1):

## TL; DR:

Google Bard is a conversational chatbot. Please consider adopting a conversational approach while designing your prompts instead of relying on a command style that solely outputs an answer. A dialogue structure would enable a more engaging and interactive experience, leading to a more effective and productive result.

---

In your conversation plan, consider to

1. Describe your context, what you need to learn or the task you must complete.
2. Describe your skills and knowledge about the topic.
   Say what you know, what you can do, what you don't know and what you can't do instead of saying, "I know the basics".
3. Ask Google Bard to give you advice about what you need to learn to do better and what to do to accomplish the task according to the time and budget that you have.
4. Based on the Google Bard responses, you could ask it to give you an explanation or give details.
5. If something is incorrect, ask Google Bard how that thing could be verified, then ask to verify it or a source to back its claim.

## Alphabet, Pronunciation and Audience Background

In this case, the topic concerns the alphabet, pronunciation and words in French. Please bear in mind that the approach is different in places where the main language is French, as in bilingual places where French is learned as a second language. When you explain the context to Google Bard, you should explain the intended audience considering the age, the location, if French is their mother tongue, etc.

## Addendum

I don't know anything about French, but I'm an International user and have been using a broad range of Google tools at an advanced level for more than ten years.

Most Google tools have separate settings for user interface language and tool input / output languages. By default, the settings are inherited from the Google account, but some tools might get personalized data based on the user's location, among other parameters.

If you aren't in a French-speaking location and are willing to go deep into how Google Bard is working now (considering that it's a novel product, with very few weeks since it was launched), consider having a specific account to be used to interact with Google Bard, and other Google products using French.

### Preparation

1. Create a new account. If you can do this while visiting a French-speaking country, the better.
2. Set the account language to French.
3. Create a new Chrome profile to be used for this account.
   This profile should automatically be set to use French; you can double-check that the Chrome language is set to French.
4. Go to Google Search.
5. Set the Location to a French-speaking location.
6. To make Google personalization lean toward French grammar and spelling, search and navigate starting from a Google search result. Use the Google Search feature and Chrome bookmarks.
7. Considering that this question is about phonetics, spend more time on site about phonetics.
8. Look if Google has a pronunciation tool in French. If it is available in French, I suggest you use it.
   In English, the keyword is `pronounce`, i.e, [pronounce philharmonic](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=pronounce%20philharmonic)

   [image: Google pronunciation tool]

### Google Bard

Go to Google Bard, and start the interaction. Remember, it's designed to have conversations, in other words, to have a lot, compared with Google Search, of back and forth.